# React useReducer vs. useState

Tags: reactjs

I've been following this tutorial with the purpose of understanding more about Context [how-to-share-state-across-react-components-with-context](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-state-across-react-components-with-context)

But for the first time I came across useReducer here and I have a mental block now, trying to re-write useReducer into useState (just for the sake of understanding how it would work with useStae and not useReducer). Here the sandbox:

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-salad-maker-sr1vt)

Basically in the SaladMaker.js I have the reducer function, which is as simple as that

```
function reducer(state, item) {
  return [...state, item];
}
```

How I understand it just pushes SaladItem into a salad array. The state gets updated:

```
const [salad, setSalad] = useReducer(reducer, []);
```

Then in SaladItem.js I actually define, how the item, which gets pushed into Salad onClick looks like:

```
function update() {
    setSalad({
      name,
      image, 
      id: `${name}-${id}`,

    });
    updateId(id+1);
  };
```

So my question is, how to convert useReducer into useState. Basically this bit:

```
const [salad, setSalad] = useReducer(reducer, []);
```

Into this bit:

```
const [salad, setSalad] = useState([]);
```

Where and how to integrate reducer function?

Comment: A big confusion is you've started with `setSalad` that *adds an item*, and you want to change to `setSalad` that *replaces the array*.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you first question which, as i understood, is how to change a reducer to a State, it's pretty simple like you wrote just converting your

```js
const [salad, setSalad] = useReducer(reducer, []);
```

to

```js
const [salad, setSalad] = useState([]);
```

and after that how you can update the state will look something like:-

```js
setSalad({salad_name : "name", image_url: "url", _id: "some-id"])
```

or if you want to update an already existing state :-

```js
// having in mind that you only have on array
const previousState = salad;
previousState.image_url = "updated_image"

setSalad(previousState)

// if you have multiple ones either you should have the index of that item or  it's _id

setSalad(
       salad.map((salad) =>
         // here you insert a id argument to the function and update it
         salad._id === 'avocado-0' // the argument ID
             ? { ...salad, name: "a New Salad " }
             : { ...salad }
       )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't do a trick, unfortunatelly. Basically salad state gets updated, but somehow update function breaks after first click, stating that salad.map is not a function in <SaladSummary> component ... Please see the sandbox above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, now I see the issue more clearly. The status get's updated, but the items get re-written, not all added to the same array...

Comment: Well yes i double checked and the salad maker was working...

Answer (score 0):

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

However, to convert the `useReducer` to a `useState` I'm gonna use this state as an example:

```
    const [salad, setSalad] = useState({
        name: "salad",
        color: "green"
    });
    function reducer(action) {
     switch (action.type) {
      case 'change_name':
       setSalad(salad => ({
        ...salad,
        name: action.payload,
       }));
      case 'change_color':
       setSalad(salad => ({
        ...salad,
        color: action.payload,
       }));
      default:
       throw new Error();
     }
   }
```

That is the case you have a state as an object. If you want the state to be an array of objects then you would ideally use an id to identify each object:

```
    const [salads, setSalads] = useState([{
        id: "1",
        name: "salad",
        color: "green"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "salad",
        color: "green"
    }
    ]);
    function reducer(id, saladUpdate) {
     setSalads(salads => salads.map(salad => salad.id !== id ? 
      {...salad} :
      {
       ...salad,
       ...saladUpdate
      }
     ))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess all the answers state the same, but to follow DRY rules, that is what had to change:

SaladMaker.js

```
const [salad, setSalad] = useState([]);
```

SaladItem.js

```
function update() {
    setSalad(salad => [ ...salad, {
      name,
      image, 
      id: `${name}-${id}`,

    }]);
    updateId(id+1);
  };
```

That's it. All other files stay same. Basically function update now does, what reducer did in useReducer.